# Does increasing height of column in a brita filter decrease the time it takes to filter?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Using conservation of mass Min=Mout I would think not but with Bernoulli's equation I get confused. (due to density being constant and same with the area I'd think the velocity has to stay constant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Water pressure increases with depth, the higher the water pressure, the faster it will be forced through a restrictive filter. So if you are talking about the water pitchers with a reservoir on top that feeds water into a filter to drain filtered water into the bottom of the pitcher, then  yes, the higher the water level above the filter, the faster it will flow. But they only hold a few inches of water, so the difference is minor. For the filters attached to a faucet, or water line, it will depend on your water pressure, water saver faucet restrictors, or other water delivery factors.

Comment: I understand that much but can you use the conservation of mass (transient state formula) to solve it? If not why not?

Comment: it is simply a pressure to flow rate equation, higher pressure causes higher flow rate

Comment: Water does not compress, so it's transient time would be it's speed of sound.